# send video in email

Tags: asp.net, email, html-email

Is it possible to send video as part of the html template ?

I mean I'd like to add `<object />` tag to emails body , as was expected it doesn't work.

video is not shown. Is it possible to do at all ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Video only works in Apple Mail - http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/video/